# How to run lower version creating iPhone app to upper version of Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I created an app at the the SDK version '2.2.1' now i am using SDK Version 3.2.6. But when i am running this app at 3.2.6 version then I am getting an error message like bellow:

error : There is no SDK with the name or pathe 'iphoneos 2.2.1'

Now how i can run this app into this version?

Answer (score 2):

As you update Xcode to newer versions, the older SDK's are removed. You need to choose the newer SDK (iOS 4, for example), and then on the Deployment Target choose you target version where the application will run (2.2.1 if that's what you want).

Answer (score 1):

You need to build using the latest version of the iOS SDK (and preferably the latest version of Xcode). For backwards compatibility you can build to version 3.0, but I think it has to be built with the latest tools still. When you submit, it asks if it was built with iOS 4.0.